# Cordova - Cannot find name 'FirebaseCrashlytics'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, firebase-crash-reporting

Goal :- Want to integrate Firebase Crashlytics Plugin in ionic 3 project.

Issue :- There is no ionic native Firebase Crashlytics plugin available for ionic 3 but it is available for ionic 4 here is [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics)

Is there any way to integrate available ionic 4 native plugin in ionic 3?
I tried integrating using cordova itself by following this [link](https://github.com/ReallySmallSoftware/cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics) but i am getting "Cannot find name 'FirebaseCrashlytics'" error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on device? I mean is cordova available ?

Comment: Yes i am testing on device(cordova available)

Answer (score 0):

If you are following a v4 guide and trying to retrofit it to Ionic 3 then one important thing to realise is the `/ngx` is not required.

If you have a line like this:

```
import { FirebaseCrashlytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-crashlytics/ngx';
```

Then change it to:

```
import { FirebaseCrashlytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-crashlytics';
```

The `ngx` requirement was introduced in Ionic 4 and is not understood by Ionic 3.

I don't know if there are other complications with trying to use a plugin with an Ionic 3 app but that's a good starting point.

Don't forget you should be following this [generic setup process](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/) for all modules that you add to a project - and don't include `/ngx` on the end there either.